# how to display data from database in card ui using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Card UI]

Hi Everyone I am newbie to web development so can you help me to solve below questions

Questions to be solved

1) suggest me best UI design to implement in web as above in image.

2) And From the database,I need to display data as above image in html by using any one of the scripting language JavaScript and Jquery. if there any other scripting language that can be used to optimize performance please suggest me with a code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can only suggest on something that is visible. A code/research/information which caters your problem. This is not a freelance portal ;)

Comment: i am not asking to built a website. i asked only for suggestion for how to implement  like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css:

```css
.card {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  width: 430px;
  height: 95px;
  position: relative;
}
.card img {
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
          border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 23px 19px;
}
.card h2 {
  color: #333;
  margin: 30px 0 12px 0;
}
.card h3 {
  color: #4e4e4e;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.card h2, .card h3, .card .time {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.card .time {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 30px;
  color: #676767;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Avatar_girl_face.png"/>
  <h2>Trevor Hansen</h2>
  <h3>So tasty!</h3>
  <div class="time">1d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use underscore.js or mustache.js. You can have a card ui that is templated with mustache.js and the data is filled in the card through json file. Where that json file lives is up to you. Mostly, it can live your server and then you can do an ajax call for the data.

https://mustache.github.io/

See demo: 
https://mustache.github.io/#demo

// Mustache + HTML

```
    <h1>{{header}}</h1>
{{#bug}}
{{/bug}}

{{#items}}
  {{#first}}
    <li><strong>{{name}}</strong></li>
  {{/first}}
  {{#link}}
    <li><a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/link}}
{{/items}}

{{#empty}}
  <p>The list is empty.</p>
{{/empty}}

//JSON
{
"header": "Colors",
  "items": [
      {"name": "red", "first": true, "url": "#Red"},
      {"name": "green", "link": true, "url": "#Green"},
      {"name": "blue", "link": true, "url": "#Blue"}
  ],
  "empty": false
}
```